# How to check if result matches an existing value in Google Sheets column and display a message in HTML page if it does?

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-apps-script, qr-code

I'm making a Google Web App where QR codes can be scanned, which returns a text value (using a QR server API in Google Sheets). Currently, the working code that I got from a tutorial is written such that when the QR code is scanned, it gets the decoded text, which it then displays in the page and adds to Column A. If the previous result matches the next (duplicate), it doesn't work. However, if you scan the same QR between a different QR, duplicates still happen since it only checks for last result. What I would like is for the function to check in the sheets first if the decoded text is already existing (in the sheets, not just in the open webpage), and if it is, display a message saying "Already existing." Otherwise, add the text to the sheets.

Here is the working code:

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet=ss.getSheets()[0];
function doGet() {
  var tmpl=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  return tmpl.evaluate().setTitle('index');
  
}

function sendback(x){
   var y=sheet.getLastRow()+1;
   sheet.getRange(y, 1).setValue(x);
   return "ok";
}


HTML Code

     
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/html5-qrcode@2.0.9/dist/html5-qrcode.min.js"></script>
    

      <script type="text/javascript">
            var resultContainer = document.getElementById('qr-reader-results');
            var lastResult, countResults = 0;

            async function onScanSuccess(decodedText, decodedResult) {
                if (decodedText !== lastResult) {
                    ++countResults;
                    lastResult = decodedText;
                    // Handle on success condition with the decoded message.
                    console.log(`Scan result ${decodedText}`, decodedResult);
                    
                    google.script.run.sendback(decodedText);
                    await waitme()
                    $('#qr-reader-results').prepend("<p>" + decodedText + "</p>");
                }
            }
           setTimeout(function(){
               var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
                "qr-reader", { fps: 10, qrbox: 250 });
               html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess);
              
           },500);  
           
           function waitme(){
             promise1=new Promise(function(resolve){
               
                  setTimeout(function(){
                   
                    resolve('ok');
                  },1000)
               })
            
               return promise1;
 
           }
           
           window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  e.returnValue = '3';
            });
      </script>
```

```
GS Code
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet=ss.getSheets()[0];
function doGet() {
  var tmpl=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  return tmpl.evaluate().setTitle('index');
  
}

function sendback(x){
   var y=sheet.getLastRow()+1;
   sheet.getRange(y, 1).setValue(x);
   return "ok";
}
```

I have tried using .withSuccessHandler but can't seem to make it work, and also something like this:

```
function sendback(x) {
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // Assuming you want to check the first sheet
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == x) {
      return "fail"; 
    }
  }

  var y = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  sheet.getRange(y, 1).setValue(x);
  return "ok"; 
}
```

```
async function onScanSuccess(decodedText, decodedResult) {
    var result = await google.script.run.sendback(decodedText);
    if (result === "fail") {
        console.log("Already exists.");
    } else if (result === "ok") {
        console.log(`Scan result ${decodedText}`, decodedResult);
        $('#qr-reader-results').prepend("<p>" + decodedText + "</p>");
    }
}
```

But they either don't work or they just keep adding to the sheet anyway even if they are duplicates.

Only a beginner, would appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

javascript:

```
function onScanSuccess(obj) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((obj) => {
    if (obj.result === "fail") {
      console.log("Already exists.");
    } else if (obj.result === "ok") {
      console.log(`Scan result ${obj.text}`, obj.result);
      $('#qr-reader-results').prepend("<p>" + obj.text + "</p>");
    }
  }).sendback(obj.text);
}
```

google script:

```
function sendback(obj) {
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // Assuming you want to check the first sheet
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == obj.text) {
      obj.result = "fail"
      return obj; 
    }
  }

  var y = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  sheet.getRange(y, 1).setValue(obj.text);\
  obj.result = "ok";
  return obj; 
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. However, when I used this, no action happened (neither display message for failure nor texts were added to the sheet). Kind of lost as I'm not sure where the issue is coming from

Comment: Try it now I forgot to add the obj to the successHandler

Comment: Sorry, no action is still happening. If it would help, I could share a sample of the sheet. Maybe I am missing something

_https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Sxutgt7z8maiH_COMGbJ3pZTVrra9VablfwHwSKnmOk/edit?usp=sharing_

Comment: Well I will need you to trouble shoot the problem and find out where it is failing.